# Building a simple "settings" plugin to change textstrings on the home page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I am trying to build a little settings area to change the strings of some text (image urls & links) on the homepage via the dashboard.

I have found a useful tutorial which provides the plugin structure (http://wakeusup.com/2011/11/how-to-create-plugin-options-page-in-wordpress/) , but when I try and change the 'key' (not sure if this is the correct term, but it is  within the link) it wont display the text, tho when using 'kkpo_quote' as the key it works, I have searched both files and substituted all instances of kkpo_quote for 'exampletext' to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? and is it simple to add another key?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you correctly you just want to rename `'kkpo_quote'` and you have conflict. Not to have conflict try to replace all `'kkpo_quote'` with same name, for example: 
if you replace 
`'kkpo_quote'` with `'new_quote'` in `register_setting(KKPLUGINOPTIONS_ID.'_options', 'new_quote');` then make sure that you replace it with `'new_quote'` where ever is `'kkpo_quote'` There is 7 times apearing in that tutorial `'kkpo_quote'`